# jQuery UI. DnD from sortable to droppable (out of the list) is not stable (doesn't drop every time)

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to reuse "sortable" function in conjunction with "droppable". But when dragging from `sortable` `drop` event doesn't happen on each drop. Here is code example:

```
$(".sortable tbody").sortable({
    start: function(ev, ui) {
        console.log("start");
        var id = ui.item.children()[0].textContent;
        $(ui.item).data("id", id);
    },
    opacity: 0.5
});
$(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        console.log("drop");
        this.value = $(ui.draggable).data("id");
    }
})
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/27bom9sb/

What's wrong here and is there a better way to compound them?

**UPDATE**

After some additional testing it was found that dropping stability depends on draggable row lenth:

Here is example with short rows (stable): http://jsfiddle.net/usv496dm/1/

The same example but with longer row text (not stable): http://jsfiddle.net/usv496dm/2/

I have no idea why the stability depends on row length but now I think that this is wrong way to utilize sortable+droppable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script

> Use [tolerance property](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance)  for the droppable.
>
> Set tolerance property to "touch" or "pointer".

```
<script>
        $(function () {

            $(".sortable tbody").sortable({
                start: function (ev, ui) {
                    var id = ui.item.children()[0].textContent;
                    $(ui.item).data("id", id);
                }
            });

            $(".droppable").droppable({
                tolerance: "touch",
                drop: function (ev, ui) {
                    console.log("drop");
                    this.value = $(ui.draggable).data("id");
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Worked for me.
Hope this helps